ExposedDropdownMenuBox with editable TextField
I want to add a dropdown menu with dynamic selectable options. User inputs some text in TextField and dropdown menu options updates depending on input. When I click on TextField dropdown menu shows but when I starting click on keyboard it hides.
For now I found a solution Editable Dynamic ExposedDropDownMenuBox in Jetpack Compose but it doesn't work as epxected. I expect that dropdown menu is shown and updates depending on user input without hiding.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun docs() {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "comment", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Egypt")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {
        TextField(
            // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field for correctness.
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { selectedOptionText = it },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
            ),
        )
        // filter options based on text field value
        val filteringOptions = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }
        if (filteringOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
            DropdownMenu(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .exposedDropdownSize(true)
                ,
                properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                filteringOptions.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


So what do you have so far? Please edit your post to add the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you want to show the dropdown menu always when the user inputs some text, just Add an expanded = true inside de onValueChange in the TextField
onValueChange = { 
        selectedOptionText = it
        expanded = true
}

